# R - Aggregate function creating sub-lists

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I'm using the aggregate function to summarise some data. The data is loans data, I have the ContractNum and LoanAmount. I want to aggregate the data by StartDate, count the number of Loans and Average the loan amount.
Here is a sample of the data and the function that I use:

```
ContractNum <- c("RHL-1","RHL-2","RHL-3","RHL-3")
StartDate <- c("2016-11-01","2016-11-01","2016-12-01","2016-12-01")
LoanPurpose <- c("Personal","Personal","HomeLoan","Investment")
LoanAmount <- c(200,500,600,150)

dat <- data.frame(ContractNum,StartDate,LoanPurpose,LoanAmount)



 aggr.data <- aggregate(
  cbind(LoanAmount,ContractNum) ~ StartDate + LoanPurpose  
  ,data = dat
  ,FUN = function(x)c(count = mean(x),length(x))
)
```

When I lookat the results of the aggregate function, it looks ok:

```
> aggr.data
   StartDate LoanPurpose LoanAmount.count LoanAmount.V2 ContractNum.count ContractNum.V2
1 2016-12-01    HomeLoan              600             1               3.0            1.0
2 2016-12-01  Investment              150             1               3.0            1.0
3 2016-11-01    Personal              350             2               1.5            2.0
```

But when I look at the strucutre of it, it seems to have created a sub-list:

```
> str(aggr.data)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ StartDate  : Factor w/ 2 levels "2016-11-01","2016-12-01": 2 2 1
 $ LoanPurpose: Factor w/ 3 levels "HomeLoan","Investment",..: 1 2 3
 $ LoanAmount : num [1:3, 1:2] 600 150 350 1 1 2
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "count" ""
 $ ContractNum: num [1:3, 1:2] 3 3 1.5 1 1 2
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "count" ""
```

How do I get rid of this sub-list so that I can access each column the way I would normally access a DF? I understand that in the code I've asked to give me a mean on a ContractNum which is not meaningful, but I can just get rid of that column.

Thank you

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Your example code doesn't work maybe? You have an extra `)` when making `aggr.data`. (I'm not the downvoter btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `do.call(data.frame, ...)` on `aggr.data` to unnest the matrices.

```
aggr.data <- do.call(data.frame, aggr.data);
str(aggr.data);
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  6 variables:
# $ StartDate        : Factor w/ 2 levels "2016-11-01","2016-12-01": 2 2 1
# $ LoanPurpose      : Factor w/ 3 levels "HomeLoan","Investment",..: 1 2 3
# $ LoanAmount.count : num  600 150 350
# $ LoanAmount.V2    : num  1 1 2
# $ ContractNum.count: num  3 3 1.5
# $ ContractNum.V2   : num  1 1 2
```